# ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider on Azure App Service: Access Denied

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, webmatrix, activedirectorymembership

One of the legacy applications running on IIS 7 was recently ported to Azure App Service.

The application uses WebMatrix (Simple Membership) and Active Directory as membership providers. Upon hosting it on Azure App Service, we are getting `Access Denied` error

**web.config**

```
<membership defaultProvider="simple">
   <providers>
     <clear />
     <add name="simple" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
     <add name="AD1MembershipProvider" description="Active Directory"
               type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider" 
               applicationName="appName" connectionStringName="AD1ConnectionString" 
               connectionUsername="..." connectionPassword="..." 
               connectionProtection="None" 
               enableSearchMethods="true" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" /> 
   </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="DefaultRoleProvider">
   <providers>
     <add name="DefaultRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
   </providers>
</roleManager>


<connectionStrings>   
   <add name="AD1ConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://something.DIR/DC=something,DC=something,DC=DIR" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

The application upon start gives this error:

```
[COMException]: Access is denied.

   at System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryEntry.Bind(Boolean throwIfFail)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.IsContextValid(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryContextType contextType)
[UnauthorizedAccessException]: Access is denied.

   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.IsContextValid(DirectoryContext context, DirectoryContextType contextType)
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.DirectoryContext.isServer()
   at System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(DirectoryContext context)
   at System.Web.Security.DirectoryInformation.InitializeDomainAndForestName()
   at System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
[ConfigurationErrorsException]: Access is denied.
 (D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config line 106)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)
   at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProviders(ProviderSettingsCollection configProviders, ProviderCollection providers, Type providerType)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.InitializeSettings(Boolean initializeGeneralSettings, RuntimeConfig appConfig, MembershipSection settings)
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Security.Membership.get_Providers()
   at WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.PreAppStartInit()
   at WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode.Start()
[InvalidOperationException]: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Access is denied.
 (D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config line 106).
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethodsCore(ICollection`1 methods, Func`1 setHostingEnvironmentCultures)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InvokePreStartInitMethods(ICollection`1 methods)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded)
   at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException)
[HttpException]: The pre-application start initialization method Start on type WebMatrix.WebData.PreApplicationStartCode threw an exception with the following error message: Access is denied.
 (D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config line 106).
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
   at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

We tried disabling `WebMatrix` in both `providers` and `roleManager` but even `ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider` gives same error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure App Service runs in a [sanbox](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox) so that's why it's failing. You won't be able to allow access since you don't have access to the host OS. There are a couple of options though.

1. Deploy your app to an Azure VM and [join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/join-windows-vm) it to your local
   domain.
2. [Migrate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/migrate-adfs-apps-to-azure) your local AD authentication for your app over to Azure Active Directory and [enable AAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-aad) on your app.
3. Migrate your existing active directory over to Azure Active Directory

Option 2 will be your best option in my opinion. This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/identity/azure-ad) is architectural overview of such a hybrid cloud solution. Option 1 will cost a bit more depending on the VM size and option 3 will require extensive planning.